# How do update the URL path with react router when using dynamic content?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux

I'm trying to figure out how to get my page URL to update based on user navigation in my react app. I'm using Redux and React Router.

when the user lands on the app, the app loads data from the server over AJAX. Lets say it is a list of animals:

```
dog
cat
fish
pig
cow
```

my router is structured like so (Simplified down to the important part):

```
<div>
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
      <Route path="/animal/:currentAnimal" component={ConnectedEntityStack} />
    </Router>
  </Provider>
</div>
```

the user can swipe left and right to get to different animals, or go to an animal directly at `mywebsite.com/animal/dog`.

currently I have landing directly on the animal working.. And I have swiping working. however, the URL does not update when I change animals.

**How do I get the URL to update using react router, when the "routes" are dynamic values (and not hard-coded into the router)?**

Comment: with `react-router` you use `browserHistory.push(newUrl)`, it can be slightly different if you're also using `react-router-redux` https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using react-router-redux, u can update url in this way:

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';

pushUrl = (newUrl) => {
  const { dispatch } = this.props;
  dispatch(push(newUrl));
}
```